# Range queries on multi-values fields in lucene

Tags: lucene, solr, full-text-search

How does Solr support range queries on multi-valued fields? (when Lucene by itself doesn't support it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene does support range queries on multi-valued fields. See below:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have realized that lucene does support range queries on multi-valued fields after logging this question. I don't know how to delete/close this question.